# Intuitive file sorting in batch scripts?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, batch-processing

So in Windows Explorer, I have these files sorted like this:

[image]

I have this script to remove the brackets and one zero, and in case the trailing number is greater than or equal to 10, to remove two zeroes:

```
cd C:\folder
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


SET /A COUNT=0

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    SET /A COUNT+=1
    ECHO !COUNT!
    set f=%%a
    IF !COUNT! GTR 9 (
        set f=!f:^00 (=!
    ) ELSE (
        set f=!f:^0 (=!
    )
    set f=!f:^)=!
    ren "%%a" "!f!"
)
pause
```

However, once I run the code, I get this result:

[image]

So the batch file isn't going through the files "intuitively" like Windows Explorer shows them. Is there any way to change this? Or is there a better way to rename these files altogether?

Comment: Stop removing the zero from the left of numbers less than 10.

Comment: Whoops- there's a mistake in the code I pasted above. I need to remove one 0 regardless of the number, but two if the number is >= 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a different approach:

```
@echo off
cd C:\folder
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /A COUNT=0, REMOVE=2

for /F "delims=(" %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg') do (
    SET /A COUNT+=1
    ECHO !COUNT!
    set "f=%%a"
    IF !COUNT! EQU 10 SET "REMOVE=3"
    for /F %%r in ("!REMOVE!") do set "f=!f:~0,-%%r!"
    ren "%%a" "!f!!COUNT!.jpg"
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost does what I need it to do- but for the second, third and fourth files there's a space between the zeroes and the number. e.g.:
"test-this_01 SELR_Opening_00000 3"
I've tried tweaking your code but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I fixed a couple small details... Copy the code again.

Comment: You need to explicitly ask for sorting (/on). Without it, the order of output of the dir command is unspecified. On FAT volumes, it will look random.

Comment: @RaymondChen, your thoughts are correct, but `dir /O` does alphabetic sorting like `1 < 10 < 2`, although alphanumeric sorting like `1 < 2 < 10` was required; as far as I can remember, NTFS does alphanumeric sorting; hence it would be better to state NTFS as a restriction for this script to work properly...

Comment: The sort order is formally unspecified, although in practice on NTFS, assuming your hard drive was formatted in the United States, this is alphabetical, *not* alphanumeric. I just tried it and the file a10 comes before a2. (The NTFS sort order actually depends on where you formatted your hard drive; the collation table is set at format time.)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a method that does not depend on the sort order used by the file system, preserving the numbers as occurring in the original file names.**

For each file name (for instance, `test_this_01 SELR_Opening_00000 (1).jpg`), the portion after the last under-score `_` is retrieved (`00000 (1)`). Then the parentheses and the space are removed and then the length is trimmed to five characters (`00001`). This string replaces the original one in the file name finally (`test_this_01 SELR_Opening_00001.jpg`); the file name must not contain the replaced portion (`00000 (1)`) multiple times (hence file names like this should not occur: `test_this_00000 (1) SELR_Opening_00000 (1).jpg`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "LOCATION=."
set "PATTERN=*_* (*).jpg"
set /A "DIGITS=5"

pushd "%LOCATION%" || exit /B 1
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%F in (`
    dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C "%PATTERN%"
`) do (
    set "FILE=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LAST="
    for %%I in ("!FILE:_=","!") do (
        set "LAST=%%~nI" & set "FEXT=%%~xI"
        set "FNEW=!FILE:%%~I=!"
    )
    set "LAST=!LAST:(=!" & set "LAST=!LAST:)=!"
    set "LAST=!LAST: =!" & set "LAST=!LAST:~-5!"
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!FNEW!!LAST!!FEXT!"
    endlocal
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

Adapt the directory location and the file search pattern in the top section of the script as you like.

After having tested, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command** in order to actually rename files.